# How do I advertise my freelance services effectively?

Tags: attracting-clients, advertising, information-technology

I've attempted a couple advertising campaigns on Facebook and Yelp, but after $250 on Yelp and $20 on Facebook I have nothing to show for it. What can I do to get more clients? I specifically do IT contracting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach of picking up jobs online, coupled with some good linkedin will serve you well.

Also, general networking and industry conferences are a great way to meet other people in your field or looking for people in your field.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by picking up jobs online?

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson Use one of the many freelancer job sites out there. Freelancer.com, Upwork, Gumtree, craigslist, even reddit

Comment: I see. I didn't know about most of those. Thanks!